# Edit or remove annotations in already saved pdf with pdf.js

Tags: pdf.js, pdf-annotations

Is there a way to change (select, edit, remove) already saved annotations within a pdf in pdf.js?

So what i want to realize is:

1. Add Annotations with pdf.js to a pdf
2. Save the document
3. Reload the pdf with the saved annotations
4. Change these annotations

Is this a functionality that is supported within pdf.js?